# Angular 7: How to access/send only body part of HTTP Response from test case

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm creating unit test cases in Angular 7 for a [Component with async service](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service).

here is my component file :

```
  submitLoginForm() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      // send a http request to save this data
      this.guestUserService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
        result => {
          // if (result) {
          if (result['token']) { // The value of result is coming the complete HttpResponse. 
            localStorage.setItem('authToken', result['token']);
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log('error', error.message);
          this.router.navigate(['/error']);
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.validateAllFields(this.loginForm);
    }
  }

}
```

the unit test case:

```
fdescribe('LoginComponent', () => {
    let component: LoginComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
    let guestUserService: any;
    let guestUserServiceSpy: any;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        guestUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj('GuestUserService', ['login']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [LoginComponent, ErrorComponent, RegistrationComponent],
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientModule,
                AppRoutingModule,
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
                { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
                { provide: GuestUserService, useValue: guestUserService }]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

  it('should Successfully Submit Registration Form', async(inject([Router], (router) => {
        guestUserServiceSpy = guestUserService.login.and.returnValue(of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: { result: { token: 'DummyTokenIsSent' } } })));

        spyOn(router, 'navigate');
        spyOn(component, 'submitLoginForm').and.callThrough();

        component.loginForm.controls['username'].setValue('hasnani@vishal.com');
        component.loginForm.controls['password'].setValue('12345678');

        component.submitLoginForm();

        expect(component.submitLoginForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.loginForm.invalid).toBe(false);

        expect(guestUserService).toBeDefined();
        expect(guestUserServiceSpy).toBeDefined();
        expect(guestUserServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/dashboard']);
    })
    ));
```

The value of result while running the test case:

[image]

I found that the error is coming as the code is not going through this part 
"if (result['token'])" 
But how to access or send body part of the http response form unit test case without effecting the component part.

Answer (score 1):

use `HttpClientTestingModule` as import and mock your http response:

```
httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
const req = httpMock.expectOne(`path`);
expect(req.request.method).toBe("GET");
req.flush({fakeresponse:true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my major focus is to test the working of the Component function not to verify the method of service file. Can you please help to either elaborate your answer or other possible ways for this type of situation.

Comment: your code inside if is never reached because your fake response has no direkt property "token". Adjust your code like this: `guestUserService.login.and.returnValue(of({ result: { token: 'DummyTokenIsSent' } } ));`

Comment: Thanks, i have changed the code like this : guestUserServiceSpy = guestUserService.login.and.returnValue(of({ token: 'DummyTokenIsSent'} ));
To fulfil the if condition.